# Rank() Over with multiple Partition

Tags: sql, t-sql, rank, partition

I'm trying to find how many times a ticket change ownergroup. I'm using this query:

```
SELECT        
TICKETID, CHANGEDATE, OWNERGROUP, 
RANK() OVER (Partition by TICKETID, OWNERGROUP ORDER BY CHANGEDATE) rk
FROM TKSTATUS where TICKETID= '12345' order by CHANGEDATE
```

And got this Result Set:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1WqZr.jpg)

After I count the 1... and get 4.

I expect this result but cannot find how I can do this:

```
RK
1
1
2
1
2
3
1
1
1
2
3
```

and result to be 6.

I know it's not the way to do it because it group the `TICKETID` and `OWNERGROUP` before the rank.

I'll continue to find a way to do this but I would like to see if someone have some ideas.

Comment: Mention all columns in the expected result, not just the `RK`.

Comment: I guess OP wants RK to restart based on `changedate` if corresponding `OWNERGROUP` also changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server 2012 you can use `lag()` to see the number of `OwnerGroup` changes by comparing the current row value with the previous row value of `OwnerGroup`.

```
select 
    TicketId
  , ChangeDate
  , OwnerGroup
  , OwnerGroupChange = case 
      when coalesce(OwnerGroup,'') 
          = lag(coalesce(OwnerGroup,'')) over (partition by TicketId order by ChangeDate)
        then 0 
    else 1 
    end
from TkStatus
where TicketId = '12345'
order by ChangeDate
```

---

To just get the number of changes you can use the above as a subquery or common table expression:

```
select 
    TicketId
  , OwnerGroupChange = sum(OwnerGroupChange) 
from (
  select 
      TicketId
    , ChangeDate
    , OwnerGroup
    , OwnerGroupChange = case 
        when coalesce(OwnerGroup,'') 
            = lag(coalesce(OwnerGroup,'')) over (partition by TicketId order by ChangeDate)
          then 0 
      else 1 
      end
  from TkStatus
  where TicketId = '12345'
  ) s
```

---

Prior to SQL Server 2012, you can use `outer apply()` to get the previous `OwnerGroup` like so:

```
select 
    t.TicketId
  , t.ChangeDate
  , t.OwnerGroup
  , OwnerGroupChange = case 
      when coalesce(t.OwnerGroup,'') = coalesce(x.OwnerGroup,'')
        then 0 
    else 1 
    end
from TkStatus t
  outer apply (
    select top 1
      i.OwnerGroup
    from TkStatus i
    where i.TicketId = t.TicketId
      and i.ChangeDate < t.ChangeDate
    order by i.ChangeDate desc
    ) x
where t.TicketId = '12345'
order by t.ChangeDate
```

Comment: Thanks! sorry for the delay for the comments... but works well!

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT        
    TICKETID, CHANGEDATE, OWNERGROUP, 
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (Partition by TICKETID ORDER BY CHANGEDATE) as RK
    FROM TKSTATUS where TICKETID= '12345' order by CHANGEDATE
```

Answer (score 0):

you could possibly use a CTE and the LAG function like this:

```
WITH CTE_Tickets as 
(  SELECT        
        TICKETID, CHANGEDATE, OWNERGROUP, 
        LAG(OWNERGROUP, 1) OVER (Partition by OWNERGROUP ORDER BY CHANGEDATE, OWNERGROUP ) as Prev
        FROM TKSTATUS where TICKETID= '12345')


    SELECT        
       TICKETID, CHANGEDATE, OWNERGROUP, Prev ,
       IIF(OWNERGROUP=Prev, 0, 1)  as changestatus
       FROM CTE_Tickets
       ORDER BY CHANGEDATE  , OWNERGROUP
```